# Rspec test to check the value of created object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

I am a newbie to Rspec. I have written an rspec which checks the create action of a controller called "Lead controller". Now I want to write a spec which checks the attribute called "status" is set to "LEAD".I want to check it from post data from the app after creating the lead. How do I use 'expect' block and 'post :create' to check status?

```
describe 'POST #create' do
    it "should create a lead" do
      my_lead = Fabricate(:project, id:  Faker::Number.number(10))
      expect{
      post :create, project: my_lead.attributes
      }.to change(Project, :count).by(1)
    end
     it "should assign the status to lead" do
       my_lead = Fabricate(:project, id:  Faker::Number.number(10))
       my_lead.status.should == "LEAD"
     end

  end
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code as well?

Answer (score 3):

Your second test has to test if the status of the created object is set as expected:

```
describe '#create' do
  let!(:my_lead) { Fabricate(:project, id:  Faker::Number.number(10)) }

  it "should create a lead" do
    expect{ post :create, project: my_lead.attributes }
      .to change(Project, :count).by(+1)
  end

  it "should assign the status to lead" do
    post :create, project: my_lead.attributes
    expect(Project.last.status).to eq('LEAD')
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Jethroo Thanks for your solution.:) But When I do this, 2 Projects are getting created: Failure/Error: expect{ post :create, project: my_lead.attributes }.to change(Project, :count).by(1) expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 2

Comment: oh right, the let block is called in the expect block so you create my_lead and the one in the controller action, you can either do a let! (creates the object directly before the test and not just on first call) or better just pass a hash with values to the post :create (makes your test faster since you are hitting the db only once)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `assigns(:instance_variable_name)` method to access an assigned instance variable in your controller.

For instance, suppose your `create` action looked like this:

def create
  @lead = Project.create(project_params)
end

Then you could access `@lead` in your RSpec controller example by calling `assigns(:lead)`. Note the symbol text exactly matches the instance variable name.

So, your updated test would look something like this:

```
 it "should assign the status to lead" do
   my_lead = Fabricate(:project, id:  Faker::Number.number(10))

   post :create, project: my_lead.attributes

   # Test that the status for @lead in our controller matches what we expect it to:
   assigns(:lead).status.should == "LEAD"
 end
```

Comment: Hi Anthony Thanks for your solution.:) But When I do this, 2 Projects are getting created:  
Failure/Error:
       expect{
       post :create, project: my_lead.attributes
       }.to change(Project, :count).by(1)
     
       expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 2

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came up with a small change which solved my problem

```
describe 'POST #create' do
    it "should create a lead" do
      my_lead = Fabricate(:project, id:  Faker::Number.number(10))
      expect{
      post :create, project: my_lead.attributes
      }.to change(Project, :count).by(1)
    end
    it "should assign the status to lead" do
      my_lead = Fabricate(:project, id:  Faker::Number.number(10))
      post :create, project: my_lead.attributes
      expect(Project.last.status).to eq('LEAD')
    end
  end
```